# Send json command to local application that listens to TCP port 5500 via javascript from web browser

Tags: javascript, json, tcp, web

I have an application that listens to TCP port number 5500 and has an API that responds to json commands. All i want to do is to send json message to the application from web browser via JavaScript and receive json response from the application.

I had tried to do so using JQuery as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="/" id="searchForm">
     <input type="submit" value="Call" />
   </form>
<!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
 /* attach a submit handler to the form */
  $("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault(); 

   /* get some values from elements on the page: */
   var $form = $( this ),
     term = '{"type" : "command","command" : "call","target" :"demo@vsee.com"}',
     url = "http://localhost:5500";

   /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
   $.post( url, term);


});
</script>
```

but it isn't working,

Any Idea?

Comment: Have you set any cross origin resource sharing headers in your local application?

Comment: So, what is your question? It's not submitting?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your application is successfully sending a response, you need to do something with it.  Try something like this:

```
$.post( url, term, function(response){
    // I'm assuming you're getting a plain text response
    // If it's JSON, you'll want to parse it first
    $('#result').text(response);
});
```